# C++ Win32 API offline documentation?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm learning win32 apps with C++. I've got a pretty good API reference, but it's from 1997.  Is there a more modern version available for download?

My connection is horrendous so I'd like it to be fully accessible offline.  Something akin to a chm or hlp file...searchable and up to date-ish.

Comment: Can you share the 1997 API reference books, so that while researching we atleast get some handy books.

Comment: @YumYumYum this was quite a few years ago now and I've moved on to different projects now. Unfortunately I don't remember what the reference was, but it was probably pretty easy to find since there's not too many out there.  Sorry about that and good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx), it comes with all the documentation as well. The download is *enormous* though, but at least you can do it all-at-once.

Comment: Only 21h 54m to go...21:53...cheers mate looks like this will do the trick for now.  Enormous, exhaustive, offline.

Comment: LINK  IS NOT WORKING PLEASE RENEW OR SHARE SOME OFFLINE, GITHUB OR DROPBOX LINKS PLEASE.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another download which is just the documentation (and slightly out-of-date, but still covers 99% of the Win32 API): [MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7bbe5eda-5062-4ebb-83c7-d3c5ff92a373)

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at this too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am looking for it.

Comment: Also little older Vista SDK http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=14477 "Software Development Kit Update for Windows Vista" contains additional content on Win32 API. For some reason MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 has some content striped out. I keep both MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and Software Development Kit Update for Windows Vista with me for offline Win32 API reference.

Comment: Can you share the NEW version 2017 is now running.

Comment: @YumYumYum: I don't think there is an offline version that's updated with Windows 10 APIs

Answer (score 3):

For complete reference of Win32 API(of course the content is still slightly out of date) I keep both [MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7bbe5eda-5062-4ebb-83c7-d3c5ff92a373)
and [Software Development Kit Update for Windows Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=14477)
Because for some reason the 2008 SP1 contains stripped down content.

[image]